# SQLite update trigger issue

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Using SQLite Manager I'm trying to create a trigger that updates a field based on another field being changed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER staff_update
AFTER UPDATE OF c_doctor ON tickets
WHEN OLD.c_doctor <> NEW.c_doctor
BEGIN
    UPDATE tickets
    SET c_doctor_staff_contact =  doctor_staff_contact.c_doctor_staff_contact 
    WHERE NEW.c_doctor = doctor_staff_contact.c_doctor;
END
```

`c_doctor` is the name of the field in the `tickets` table as well as `doctor_staff_contact` table. `doctor_staff_contact` is also the name of a field in those tables.

`SET c_doctor_staff_contact = "test"; END` works, so my assumption is `=  doctor_staff_contact.c_doctor_staff_contact WHERE NEW.c_doctor = doctor_staff_contact.c_doctor; END` is giving me issues. As far as I can tell I'm doing it right.

```
= c_doctor_staff_contact IN (SELECT c_doctor_staff_contact FROM doctor_staff_contact
    WHERE NEW.c_doctor = doctor_staff_contact.c_doctor);
END
```

This works but changes `c_doctor_staff_contact` to 0, and changes all the other tickets `c_doctor_staff_contact` to 0 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UPDATE` query in the trigger body should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER staff_update
AFTER UPDATE OF c_doctor ON tickets
WHEN OLD.c_doctor <> NEW.c_doctor
BEGIN
    UPDATE tickets
    SET c_doctor_staff_contact = (
        SELECT c_doctor_staff_contact 
        FROM doctor_staff_contact
        WHERE NEW.c_doctor = c_doctor
        )
    WHERE NEW.c_doctor = c_doctor;
END;
```